# Concurrent thread group execution on same application is failing few sampler in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am rookie to Jmeter. 
I have been asked to run multiple thread groups where there is a single Testplan. 
All these Thread groups perform different scenarios on same application.
but running them concurrently is failing few samplers, on the other hand if i run them sequentially then everything works well.

so can anyone guide me on this as what can be done.

Details:

there are 3 samplers.
1. Login with post form
2. Get case status page
3. Logout

- Unique key generated from Login page response is RANDOM_TOKEN_KEY which I am capturing and passing it to "Get case status page".
- JsessionID is getting generated uniquely for individual steps hence i have skip that one.
- From case status page I am directly clicking on Logout page which is working fine.

Issue: when this test is triggered for more than 1 threads, example 10 at same time. then Login is working fine but "Get case status page" sample is throwing error as "Your current session has expired. Please log in again."

[Script failed when run concurrently with same user credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp0Li.png)

Comment: please post the error message. You need to add more details to your question. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, please check that as i have details.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the checkbox "Delay Thread creation until needed" in Thread Group.

This way threads will work without interrupting the flow.